# Creating a character restriction on an email field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey. I'm creating an input field (`<input type="text" value="" />`) that my user will enter their email in, but I am also using a live alphanumeric character restriction on that field (in jQuery) with the exception of the characters, `.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_{|}~@`. I'm wondering if it is worth it to do all this checking, or to just say "Hey, invalid email" when they hit submit? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The hole checking is quite useless, because even checked you have no guarantee that the string is a valid email address. The mta will do an effective checking for you, when you try to send anything to the entered email address. Why do you want to duplicate the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not something you need to do in a given way, entirely your choice, but I think it's helpful for a user to get the error while filling a form and not after it, so he should go back and change it, it's a bit more time consuming. I personally did this on every registration form I've done.

If you mean only server side check under "when they hit submit" then you should really do a jquery check on the input as well, you spare traffic with it, also you need to do both server side and client side checking.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere to use mask for formated fields like phones or emails, that way you sensure the format and the user won't get lost on what to input.

May you take a look at this:

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/mask/demos/mask/default.html

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137996/mask

Answer (score 0):

How about not restricting the characters, but rather checking the value against a simple regexp? You can do this live. This is an interesting article: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html
I would still check it after submission, some users may have JS disabled.

Comment: But what are the chances they do? I mean, you almost can't use the internet without JS enabled (except for when using NoScript).

Comment: Checking after submission *ensures* that your application saves valid data. By reducing the number of characters you *hope* that the user will do as you expect. How about I will manually send a post request to your site and you will not check the data before saving it? Having said that, checking after submission is part of your application, reducing characters is only a nice feature, but it does not do anything useful in terms of the app itself. It just looks cool. Oh, besides, I sometimes use lynx for browsing the net. But me, I am a nerd.